# Determinant and Inverse of a Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrix-inverse, toeplitz-operators

Let $T(n,k)$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric Toeplitz matrix, where all the entries of first $k$ super-diagonal (and sub-diagonal), last $k-1$ super-diagonal (and sub-diagonal) are ones,  and rest of the entries are zero.

> **Question 1.** Is there a nice closed formula for the determinant $\det(T(n,k))$?
>
> **Question 2.** Is there a nice expression for the inverse $T(n,k)^{-1}$?

For example $T(11, 3)$ is given by  $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},$$ having $\det(T(n,k))=0.$

Comment: You could use [Levinson Algorithm](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/1992_53.pdf) to find the determinant. As for eigenvalues, check [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/1992_53.pdf). I feel finding eigenvalues and then the determinant is exact, rather the numerical first procedure

Comment: @vidyarthi The link to Levinson Algorithm is missing, by mistake, you have linked the paper.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion) is the desired link. Sorry

Comment: The paper I referred to for eigenvalues actually is more general and talks more of non-hermitian cases and pseeudo-eigenvalues. For more straightforward treatment, you coulkd refer the classic Polya-Szego problem book, or the referred papers [12], [15] in the paper link I gave earlier

Comment: [Here](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf) is the paper that gives exact formulae for eigenvalues for tridiagonal case. Hope your case might be something similar

Comment: For $n$ odd and $k$ even, the pattern seems easiest: it looks like $\det(T(n,k))=(n+1)k/2$ unless it vanishes, which happens (if $k$ is fixed) for $n\equiv-1\pmod{\{\text{list}\}}$, e.g. for $k=14$ whenever $n\equiv-1\pmod{6,10\ \text{or} 14}$. In the other cases, the periodicities look way too irregular to be part of a general pattern.

Comment: All that of course only for $n\ge2k$.

Comment: @Wolfgang can you please give me an idea of proof for the case you mentioned; $n$ odd $k$ even.

Comment: I don't have a proof, just some computations.  :(

Comment: @Wolfgang, were you referring  to this question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265512/determinant-and-inverse-of-a-stars-and-stripes-matrix?rq=1) where T. Amdeberhan has given the determinant for a case

Comment: No I didn't, I just computed many cases. Note that in the question you mentioned it doesn't have zeros in some diagonals. And there the determinants don't depend linearly from n.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer Q1. This determinant can be calculated with the well known companion method for banded matrices. Define the $2k \times 2k$ companion matrix (here $k=3$)
$$
\mathbf{C} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as well as the two boundary matrices
$$
\mathbf C_1 = \mathbf C^{-1} \mathbf J_1, \qquad
\mathbf C_2 = \mathbf C \mathbf J_2,
$$
with
$$
\mathbf J_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\qquad
\mathbf J_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Then,
$$
\det(T(L+2k,k)) = (-1)^{k(L+1)}\det[\mathbf C^L \mathbf C_2^k - \mathbf C_1^k].
$$
The companion matrix $\mathbf C$ has eigenvalues on the unit circle (of the form $e^{\mathrm i \pi m/k}$ and $e^{\mathrm i \pi m/(k+1)}$, with integer $m$), such that it should be possible to calculate them in closed form recursively, as well as the eigenvectors. The two matrices $\mathbf C_{1,2}^k$, on the other hand, have a simple structure, as after $k$ multiplications the row of -1s is moved to the middle, e.g. for $k=5$,
$$
\mathbf C_2^k =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc|ccccc}
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
\hline
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

The observed irregular behavior stems from the mixing of matrix elements in the matrix power $\mathbf C^L$ for $L>k$.

Finally some Mathematica code for your convenience...

```
TT[n_, k_] := Table[Switch[Abs[i - j], 0, 0, _?(0<#<=k || #>n-k &), 1, _, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}]
CC[k_] := Table[If[i == 1 && j != k, -1, If[i == j + 1, 1, 0]], {i, 2 k}, {j, 2 k}]
C1[k_] := Table[If[j == 2 k && i != k + 1, If[i == 1, 0, -1], If[i == j + 1, 1, 0]], {j, 2 k}, {i, 2 k}]
C2[k_] := Table[If[i == 1 && j != k, If[j == 2 k, 0, -1], If[i == j + 1, 1, 0]], {i, 2 k}, {j, 2 k}]
det[L_, k_] := (-1)^(k(L+1)) Det[MatrixPower[CC[k], L].MatrixPower[C2[k], k] - MatrixPower[C1[k], k]]
Table[Det[TT[2 k + L, k]] - det[L, k], {L, 0, 20}, {k, 1, 20}]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dense here, but where does the formula $\det(T(L+2k,k)) = (-1)^{k(L+1)}\det[\mathbf C^L \mathbf C_2^k - \mathbf C_1^k]$ come from? I first thought Schur complementation, but it doesn't look like one at closer inspection.

Comment: @Frederico: The formula is an generalization of the determinant recursion for tridiagonal matrices with corners, see e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0681v3. While there are several works on determinants of banded matrices using companion matrices, I don't find an appropriate reference now. I worked out the case for more general corner elements myself. Normally, the formula contains the term $\det(\mathbf I + \mathbf C_L\mathbf C_{L-1} \cdots \mathbf C_1)$, however, in the present case the boundary matrices $\mathbf C_1^{-1}$ are singular. Therefore, I moved them to the unity matrix.

Comment: @Federico: Sorry, I didn't read carefully and misspelled your name. Note also that the $\mathbf C_\ell$ in my reply are ambiguous. Unfortunately, I could not edit my comment after 5 minutes :-(.

Comment: No worries, it's a very common misspelling, I am used to it. :) Thanks for the explanation, this is clearer now.